# Stop functions starting in shiny until button pressed

Tags: r, shiny

I have begun to create a web app using shiny where a user enters a search term and tweets containing that term are returned.

When I load this app the `searchTwitter` function begins automatically and on the main panel there is the error: `Error: You must enter a query.`

The search term is entered in the textInput box and there is a submitButton. You can enter a term and it works fine but I don't want the error to be the first thing the user sees.

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(  
  headerPanel("Twitter Generator"),

  sidebarPanel(    
    textInput("search", "Search Twitter For:", value = ""),    
    submitButton("Search")
    ),  

  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("search")),
    tableOutput("view"), 
    )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(twitteR)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- reactive(function(){
    rawTweets <- twListToDF(searchTwitter(paste(input$search)))
    rawTweets$cleanText <- as.vector(sapply(rawTweets$text, CleanTweet))  
    rawTweets[, colnames(rawTweets) != "created"]    
  })

  output$search <- reactiveText(function() {
    input$search    
  })

  output$view <- reactiveTable(function() {   
    head(datasetInput())
  })

})
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: My question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840803

Answer (score 1):

This is a logical request for and from your application design, and you should think through how to do it.

One easy way would be to add a tickbutton providing a true/false and to skip the actual twitter search if the value is `FALSE`.  You may need to cache the previous value of `rawTweets`, or set it to NULL, or ...

Answer (score 0):

mainPanel(

h3(textOutput("search")),

tableOutput("view") 
    )

try it without the second ","