# Action Button, adding "addResourcePath" in global.R throws error

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

The solution given for action button observe code getting executed during page load in the following link doesn't work,

[Shiny submitButton behavior at page load time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840803/shiny-submitbutton-behavior-at-page-load-time)

Adding the following code in global.R throws an error

```
addResourcePath(prefix='actionButton', directoryPath=system.file('actionButton',package='shinyIncubator'))
```

Error:

```
Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```